# ADD Link code to this code

Tags: html, image, row

Does anyone know how i can add "links" to these image row codes

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="1.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="2.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="3.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="4.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="5.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="6.jpg"></li>
<ul>
```

CSS

```
#images {
    width: 2000px;
}

#images img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/gEGMF/

Comment: Can you please provide more information about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly mean you want to add hyperlinks to the pictures? A simple `<a href='[[your URL'>[[img-tag]]</a>` should do the trick, as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gEGMF/20/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="your-link"><img src="1.jpg"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="your-link"><img src="2.jpg"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="your-link"><img src="3.jpg"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="your-link"><img src="4.jpg"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="your-link"><img src="5.jpg"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="your-link"><img src="6.jpg"/></a></li>
</ul>
```